# Magento Transactional Emails: Add new Template page is empty

Tags: email, magento, transactional

I try to customize the email template. I go to  System -> Transactional Emails -> Add new template, there is a empty page, and the template loading dropdown menu is blank.

This following show is my system.log. I don't know if it is the problem log.

> 2015-05-22T05:14:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Inventory/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/mobilestation/web/mobilestation.co.nz/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> 2015-05-22T05:14:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Inventory/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/mobilestation/web/mobilestation.co.nz/public_html/app/code/local:/home/mobilestation/web/mobilestation.co.nz/public_html/app/code/community:/home/mobilestation/web/mobilestation.co.nz/public_html/app/code/core:/home/mobilestation/web/mobilestation.co.nz/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /home/mobilestation/web/mobilestation.co.nz/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Really need the help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is some error in your Module's config.xml file. Please paste code here so that I get clear idea about your error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know where the module config.xml.

Comment: it's in app/etc/modules and find NameSpace_ModuleName.xml